# Meaning of Monen in Kabbalah

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, astronomy, sorcery-magic-kishuf, astrology

I came across the term "monen" but have been unable to find much information on it in scholarly or scriptural sources. The main information online appears to be a kabbalah-related stub on Wikipedia, which says it is a kind of astrology-related divination method. Does anyone have any further information on the topic?

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Benny and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: https://biblehub.com/hebrew/6049.htm II. [עָנַן] verb Po`. practice soothsaying (probably denominative, but original meaning dubious; connection with I. עָנָן (DeIsaiah 2:6)

Comment: @TheGRAPKE are you sure it's supposed to be Me'onen? That has something to do with divination, but what does that have to do with Kabbalah?

Comment: @Harel13 I am assuming a *ta'us ha'dephus* till provided with more sources.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual reference. Can you please provide a link in your question to the source you are looking at?

Comment: @YaacovDeane Apparently, there is a "[Monen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monen)" article on Wikipedia which states: "_Monen is a kabbalistic concept covering that branch of occultism which deals with the reading of the future by the computation of time and observation of planets and stars (astrology)_". All of it's sources seem secondary (_i.e._ it doesn't reference Kabbalah works directly). One of those is available from archive.org, and [seems](https://archive.org/details/historyofthesupe02howiuoft/page/n29/mode/2up) to be referring to a _Me'onen_, as `@TheGRAPKE` surmised.

Comment: @TamirEvan “The History of the Supernatural” by William Howitt?!! How does that have anything to do with Judaism and traditional Jewish teachings? This question is off topic.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya. It looks like the word is not "monen" but M'onein. It is a category of forbidden practice in Deuteronomy 18:10. [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.18?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.18.10.3&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=he) there brings two opinions:

> מעונן. רַבִּי עֲקִיבָא אוֹמֵר אֵלּוּ נוֹתְנֵי עוֹנוֹת – שֶׁאוֹמְרִים עוֹנָה פְּלוֹנִית יָפָה לְהַתְחִיל, וַחֲכָמִים אוֹמְרִים אֵלּוּ אוֹחֲזֵי הָעֵינַיִם:
> מעונן — Rabbi Akiba said, Such are people who assign times (עונות plural of עונה “period”, “time”) — who say, “This time is auspicious to begin some work”; the Sages, however, say, It refers to those “who hold your eyes under control” (who delude by optical deception; they connect מעונן with עין “eye”) (Sifrei Devarim 171:9).

The Wikipedia entry is probably going with the opinion of R' Akiva, and it refers to those who use astrology to find favorable times for different activities.

Comment: Thank you for your help - apologize for the lack of clarity in original question.